# Is it possible to install specific version of TFDV without upgrading TF?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, tensorflow-data-validation, version-compatibility

I have problem with installing TensorFlow Data Validation (TFDV).

I have already TensorFlow installed (version 2.5.0) and I don't want to upgrade that version.

I used this command:

*pip install tensorflow_data_validation==1.2.0*

Beacuse this TFDV version should be compatible with TF 2.5 according to: https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/data_validation/install

Unfortunately this command force me to install TF with latest version 2.8.
Is it possible to install any version of TFDV without upgrading TF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip` tries to just grab the latest compatible version with the restraints from the `tensorflow_data_validation` wheel being

```
tensorflow (!=2.0.*,!=2.1.*,!=2.2.*,!=2.3.*,!=2.4.*,<3,>=1.15.2)
```

so it makes sense that it is trying to grab tensorflow 2.8

You can try to just pin the version of tensorflow in the same command line

```
 pip install tensorflow_data_validation==1.2.0 tensorflow==2.5.0
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped with small edit:

*pip install tensorflow_data_validation==1.2.0 tensorflow==2.5.0*